# "sheaves of germs of differentiable functions are by no means coherent"?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, coherent-sheaves

This is related to a remark in Iitaka's algebraic geometry sec 1.12.

"...It should be noted that sheaves of germs of differentiable functions are by no means coherent. These facts seem to suggest coherence is linked with the property of being algebraic or analytic."

$\textbf{Q1:}$ What is the example of non-coherence for the differentiable case? First what is the sheaf of rings in the context? Is it ring of smooth functions?

$\textbf{Q2:}$ If I recall correctly, there are analytic sheaves which are not coherent.(I do not think I will recall this correctly.) Coherence is related notion to algebraic for sure but I have to use GAGA to say it is analytic. However, in analytic setting, there are non-coherent sheaves as well. Should I naively interpret coherence is subcase of analytic or algebraic?(But not the reverse in general?)

Comment: If the structure sheaf is $C^\infty$ then the module $C^\infty$ certainly is coherent over the ring $C^\infty$! So I would guess the structure sheaf should be that of algebraic or analytic functions, where it is also more or less clear that $C^\infty$ is not coherent over these rings. Seems kind of lame, maybe somebody else can elaborate.

Comment: @s.harp coherency depends upon both topological space and local module structure. You can conclude structure sheaf is quasi coherent at best. I doubt you can even conclude coherency. Say $O$ is structural sheaf. $O^n\to O$ is a map over some small open set. Why is  kernel of this necessarily finitely generated?

Comment: I see, I had not thought about that at all. For $n=1$ it seems true for $O=C^\infty$ and false for example for $O=C^0$, as the closed ideals of $C^\infty$ should be given by closed sets on which functions vanish. That might motivate it to be true for higher $n$, but its certainly not a proof!

Comment: I think you could use a little more specificity about what you mean when you say "what is the example of non-coherence", since you can always produce a noncoherent sheaf by just taking an infinite direct sum of structure sheaves. Do you mean to ask about when the structure sheaf is coherent in these various categories?

Comment: @KReiser I think I am looking for a sheaf of ring map $O\to O$ s.t. kernel of this map is not f.g. I am aware that ring of smooth functions is not noetherian. In other words, why structural sheaf as module is not coherent over itself beside being non-noetherianess?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're asking about whether the structure sheaf is coherent as there are easy examples of non-coherent sheaves over any space: take an infinite direct sum of structure sheaves.

In the $C^\infty$ case, the structure sheaf will not be coherent in general. Consider the sheaf $\mathcal{O}$ of $C^\infty$ functions on $\Bbb R$. Let $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ be the function which is $0$ for $x\leq 0$ and $e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}$ otherwise. Then $\mathcal{K}=\ker(\mathcal{O}\stackrel{f\cdot}{\to}\mathcal{O})$ is not of finite type. One can see this as follows: if $\mathcal{K}$ were of finite type, then the stalk of $\mathcal{K}$ should be of finite type over the stalk of $\mathcal{O}$ at each point. If this were true at $0$, then as $x\mathcal{K}_0=\mathcal{K}_0$, we would have that $\mathcal{K}_0=0$ by Nakayama's lemma. But it's clearly nonzero - $f(-x)$ is in it, for instance.

In the analytic case, whether or not the structure sheaf is coherent depends on the base field. For complex-analytic spaces, the structure sheaf is always coherent as a result of Oka's theorem (a hard result!). For real-analytic manifolds, the structure sheaf is again coherent, essentially because we can extend the solutions of our real-analytic equations cutting out our manifold a little bit in the complex direction and retain smoothness, and then apply Oka's theorem. For real-analytic spaces, there are no guarantees, and in fact there are real-analytic spaces which have non-coherent structure sheaves.

An example of a real-analytic variety which isn't coherent is Cartan's umbrella: $$X=\{x\in\Bbb R^3\mid x_3(x_1^2+x_2^2)-x_1^3=0\}$$ We may see that the ideal $I_X\subset \mathcal{O}_{\Bbb R^3}^{an}$ is generated at the origin by $g(x)=x_3(x_1^2+x_2^2)-x_1^3$ by complexifying and applying the Nullstellensatz. On the other hand, in a neighborhood of any point $(0,0,t)\in\Bbb R^3$ with $t\neq 0$, $M$ reduces to the line $x_1=x_2=0$ and $I_X$ is generated by $x_1,x_2$. So in a neighborhood of the origin, $I_X$ cannot be generated by $g$, which implies $I_X$ is not of finite type. As $I_X$ is the kernel of the map between the structure sheaves of $\Bbb R^3$ and $X$ in the analytic topology, this provides what you're looking for.