# Counterexamples in the theory of coherent sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, coherent-sheaves

I am looking for a few "non-intuitive" counterexamples in the theory of coherent sheaves. In particular:

- A ringed space $(X,\mathcal{O}_{X})$ so that $\mathcal{O}_{X}$ is not coherent over itself.
- A sheaf $M$ that is finitely generated over $\mathcal{O}_{X}$ but not coherent.
- I have read somewhere, but forgotten where, that if $\mathcal{O}_{X}$ is coherent over itself, then coherent and finitely generated are the same for sheaves over $\mathcal{O}_{X}$. Can anyone give me a reference or explain it to me?

Thanks.

Comment: For the first two, any non-coherent ring (regarded as the structure sheaf of a point, if you insist) will do. For example, [the ring of germs of smooth functions](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/incoherent.pdf).

Comment: This is mostly a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3333153/sheaves-of-germs-of-differentiable-functions-are-by-no-means-coherent/3333256#3333256) except that your third bullet point isn't addressed in the linked question. I recommend moving this third item to another post and then closing this as a duplicate of the linked question.

Comment: The third point is not quite right. For example, coherent modules over a coherent commutative ring are precisely the finitely presented ones, not the finitely generated.ones. I think that when $\mathcal{O}_X$ is coherent, the right notion of coherent modules are those that are locally of finite presentation.